# Jsoup get value if contains attribute

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I want to extract the value for specefic titles in the table such as;

```
    <tr>
    <th colspan="8"> 
    <a href="/wiki/Hit_points" title="Hit points" class="mw-redirect">Hit points</a>
    </th>
    <td colspan="12"> 240</td>
    </tr>
<tr>
<th colspan="8"> <a href="/wiki/Aggressive" title="Aggressive" class="mw-redirect">Aggressive</a>
</th><td colspan="12"> Yes
</td></tr>
```

I want to be able to get the value for example;

if title equals "Hit points"
 returns 240

in the above case.

```
    package test;

import org.jsoup.Connection.Response;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Attribute;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class topkek {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
        Response res = Jsoup.connect("http://2007.runescape.wikia.com/wiki/King_black_dragon").execute();
          String html = res.body();
          Document doc2 = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(html);
          Element body = doc2.body();
          Elements tables = body.getElementsByTag("table");
          for (Element table : tables) {


              if (table.className().contains("infobox")==true) {
                  System.out.println(table.getElementsByAttribute("title").text());
                  break;
              }
          }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to go through the document manually, you can simply use a selector for this:

```
response
   .parse()
   .select("th:has(a[title=\"Hit points\"]) ~ td")
   .text()
```

This selects a `th` element that has a nested `a` with the title and has a sibling `td` element from which you can read the content using `text()`

See [here](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) for syntax details and [here](http://try.jsoup.org/) for an online sandbox.

**Edit**: if you want to list multiple elements, you can use something like this:

```
document
    .select("th:has(a[title])")
    .forEach(e -> {
        System.out.println(e.text());
        System.out.println(((Element) e.nextSibling()).text());
    });
```